# Date Range slider not getting rendered in react-google-charts

Tags: reactjs, google-visualization

Screenshot showing rendered graph:
[image: Screenshot showing rendered graph]

```js
    <Chart
            width={'100%'}
            height={'600px'}
            chartType="LineChart"
            loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
            data={[
                ['Date', 'Value'],
                [new Date(1996, 1, 1), 2000 * Math.random()],
                [new Date(1997, 1, 1), 2000 * Math.random()],
                [new Date(1998, 1, 1), 2000 * Math.random()],
                [new Date(1999, 1, 1), 2000 * Math.random()],
                [new Date(2000, 1, 1), 2000 * Math.random()],
                [new Date(2001, 1, 1), 2000 * Math.random()],
                [new Date(2002, 1, 1), 2000 * Math.random()],
                [new Date(2003, 1, 1), 2000 * Math.random()],
                [new Date(2004, 1, 1), 2000 * Math.random()],
                [new Date(2005, 1, 1), 2000 * Math.random()],
                [new Date(2006, 1, 1), 2000 * Math.random()],
                [new Date(2007, 1, 1), 2000 * Math.random()],
                [new Date(2008, 1, 1), 2000 * Math.random()],
                [new Date(2009, 1, 1), 2000 * Math.random()],
            ]}
            options={{
                // Use the same chart area width as the control for axis alignment.
                chartArea: { height: '80%', width: '90%' },
                hAxis: { slantedText: false },
                vAxis: { viewWindow: { min: 0, max: 2000 } },
                legend: { position: 'none' },
            }}
            chartPackages={['corechart', 'controls']}
            controls={[
                {
                    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
                    options: {
                        filterColumnIndex: 0,
                        ui: {
                            chartType: 'LineChart',
                            chartOptions: {
                                chartArea: { width: '90%', height: '50%' },
                                hAxis: { baselineColor: 'none' },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    controlPosition: 'bottom',
                    controlWrapperParams: {
                        state: {
                            range: { start: new Date(1996, 1, 9), end: new Date(2010, 2, 20) },
                        },
                    },
                },
            ]}
        />
```

I am able to render the graph, but can't see the date range slider to control the date range, can someone please help in fixing this issue? I am trying to display time range in x-axis and some numeric data in y axis. I just copied the code from react-google-charts and didn't modify much, Is there something else I need to include in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the problem, but as you can see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/3vjp72yz5p) it works normally.

There are 2 possible causes for the problem you're having IMO :

1. You're using an old version of react-google-charts (< 3.0)
2. Some of your page css is overriding the chart height (contained in a div with a smaller height than the chart) ?

Hope that helps,

Cheers !